# Rails adding translations to a running rails environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-i18n, rails-console, i18n-gem

Is there a way to manually inject a translation through the Rails console ?

Suppose I am working on a dev environment, and I want to test some code in a production console (eg to test some statistics on real data).Problem is, the code I want to test relies on new translations that didn't exist (or were changed) in the production environment.

So my code returns a lot of `translation_missing`

Can I inject the missing translations ? Via a hash or a YML file ?

```
I18n.load_translations(hash_or_file)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually Application instances that serve http requests (for example running under Unicorn/Puma) are not available via Rails console. When someone login to production server and type `$RAILS_ENV=production rails c` it starts another application process. Translations dictionary is a kind of in-memory cache and usually it is not possible to change that cache for/from another process (in general). You can reload translations only for application instance that started by Rails console, but not for running server.

Only one way to hot reload translations is adding kind of a hook into source code of application to re-read YAML file, but it seems better just restart application server.

**UPDATE:** For testing purposes I18n cache could be modified like:

```
I18n.backend.send(:translations)[:en][:date][:formats][:default] = "%Y-%Z"
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't talking about live modifications on the running server, but really inside the rails console. Your update line covered it.